# COM+ Access Issue using Local System

Tags: sql, com

I have a COM+ component and It has access restrictions enabled , Now when I try to access the component from SQL Server (everything is enabled in SQL for accessing COM) , I am getting access denied error.
SQL is running from LOCAL System account (on Windows 8.1).

The error is as below.

```
"A method call to an object in a COM+ application was rejected because the
caller is not properly authorized to make this call. The COM+ application
is configured to use Application and Component level access checks, and 
enforcement of these checks is currently enabled. The remainder of this
message provides information about the component method that the caller 
attempted to invoke and the identity of the caller.Svc/Lvl/Imp = 10/6/1,
  Identity = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM ."
```

Access check is enabled for the COM component and security level is "Perform check and the process and component level". If I use only Process level security it will work . Or If I run SQL Server  from any other account other than Local System It will work(I have roles enabled for COM+ and added a Local  Group as the User of the role, and I have added all accounts including Local System account as a member of this group which has access to  the COM component).

As per my understanding Local System account has unrestricted access to the local resources , OR Am I missing anything else here.?